# Google map api and rhel proxy server

Tags: rhel, proxy

I have a RHEL virtual server that connects to our corporate environment via a proxy server.  Using a Google Map API from my desktop, which sits within the corporate environment, retrieves data immediately.  Using the same API from my virtual server takes 6-7 seconds to retrieve data on first attempt, but immediate thereafter.  What is it about this first attempt that causes the delay?

Comment: It could be waiting for DNS to resolve names, or it needs to get and build up some internal data structure. Try monitoring traffic during the startup.